# What’s up with the volume tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

The [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) tag is a mixup of partitioning questions and audio questions.

Could someone sort it out? (FYI it's the same mistake done by Polish Windows translators: translating "volume manager" like it had something to do with sound).

Comment: This one will be interesting. Both meanings are well-known and fit the site topics.

Comment: Split the tag in two: `volume-audio` and `volume-storage` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New questions tagged [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) will now be remapped to [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio).

This does not merge them as there are some logical and partitioning questions. For those the community will need to check out the existing questions tagged [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) and retag them as appropriate.

While you're at it, look at the body of the question and do some fixes there. The extra time you spend cleaning up the body will hopefully slow down any potential flooding of the site.

Comment: I think we should rather have the synonym to [tag:logical-drive].

Answer (score 6):

### Suggestion

1. Split these up first in [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) OR [sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound) (the [audio-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-volume) tag  is too specific) and [logical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logical-drive).
2. Make [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) a synonym of [logical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logical-drive).

### Reasoning

You can't have a single question about [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume), volume will **always** be interpreted as ambiguous even when you do keep the tag and write as much in the information of the tag as you want. In other words, it does not solve the problem that we are having now; we don't want ambiguous use of [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume).

We have to find two tags that better fit the purpose, one of them should be [logical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logical-drive). People that don't know about it will type `volume` and wonder why this tag comes up; then they read a short description and they will know that [logical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logical-drive) is what they want. The definition can be extracted from a online dictionary like [Webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/logical_drive.html), which explains this term very well:

> ### *logical drive*
>
> A part of a physical disk drive that has been partitioned and allocated as an independent unit, and functions as a separate drive altogether. For example, one physical drive can be partitioned into drives `F:`, `G:`, and `H:`, each representing a separate logical drive but all still part of the one physical drive.
>
> Using the logical drive hierarchy is one method of organizing large units of memory capacity into smaller units.

As for audio, do we *actually* want a tag that's called [volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) or [audio-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-volume)? Isn't it OK to just categorize these under [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) OR [sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound)? I don't think that the volume tags have any benefit while searching, and I think that a question that's only about the tag [audio-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-volume) can't exist.

Now the only question for this last paragraph is whether we want [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) or [sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound)...

Comment: +1 Getting rid of it is the only real solution. Logical drive, if equivalent, sounds like a good idea. Hopefully the synonym is obvious enough to not lead to mistagged questions.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Woops! Yeah, corrected now. Logical drive should be equivalent according to what I read. [Wikipedia lists both as synonymous...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_%28computing%29)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "audio-volume tag is too specific." and I disagree with your claim that "question that's only about the tag audio-volume can't exist."  [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/359138/changing-the-size-of-the-audio-volume-increment-of-the-volume-up-volume-dow) would be fine with a primary key of 'audio-volume' along with secondary ones for 'windows' and 'keys'.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: However, it is not fine when there are no secondary ones. About it being too specific, for the same reason we don't have tags called [tag:office-word-subscript]. So, the question is (as I listed in a later paragraph) whether we actually want such tag. Otherwise asked, does the tag make up for a large enough subset within [tag:audio] or [tag:sound]?

Comment: This is way more detailed than what I proposed. Never the less an excellent idea.

Comment: Why don’t you do it?

Comment: @kino: I'll look into this next week, still in my exams now...

Comment: Don’t just retag blindly. You just tagged [this question](http://superuser.com/q/292310/101850) with [tag:audio].

Comment: @kinokijuf: I'm not doing so, that's indeed one that slipped in but I've been watching the others. It became a bit annoying that you entered my progress, thanks for doing it backwards / double checking. I guess we can consider this done...

Comment: I simply searched for [hard-drive]+[audio] and [partitioning]+[audio]. Are there any other tags that could be searched for? And it’s _you_ that entered _my_ progress.

Comment: @kino: I started first, feel free to verify. But doesn't matter, it's done now...

Answer (score 1):

Volume should be used for partitioning, not audio. Disk format questions are far more prevalent.

Volume also has a specific meaning on the Windows side compared to partition. So using just partition may not be an ideal solution considering GPT will see further adoption in the coming future.

Add on the fact that Linux calls their partition manager the Logical Volume Manager.

Comment: 4 of the top 5 questions by votes are about audio IIRC. It's really not clear from the use of the tag.

Comment: It's rather uncooperative to just ignore the audio volume questions, without even providing a suggested alternate tag.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: My bad. Call it [Loudness].

Comment: @surfasb, that's not perfect, but it's a reasonable candidate.  However, I can't remove my downvote until someone edits your answer.

Comment: NP, I'm not sure if I need more rep at this point.  I just need to answer a question which happens to get tons of views.

Comment: Non-MSO Meta votes don't affect reputation, neither for the voter, nor the "votee". It's just a measure of community opinion about a post.